# In what states is the left lane only for passing?

Tags: usa, driving

On a recent road trip, a cop pulled us over to let us know that we'd been in the left lane for a while and in that state, the left lane was solely for passing people. He noticed our out-of-state plates and figured we didn't know. He was right: in my home state, I generally sit in the left lane for ages when I'm going a long way, since I drive rather fast.

In what states are you not supposed to linger in the left lane? I don't want to get in trouble when road tripping in the future.

Comment: Here's a [start for you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_lane). Here's an [even better](http://www.mit.edu/~jfc/right.html) page.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://www.mit.edu/%7Ejfc/right.html):

## States which only allow passing in the left lane:

- Arkansas
- Illinois
- Kentucky
- Louisiana
- Maine
- Massachusetts
- New Jersey

## States which require slower traffic to move right:

- Alabama
- Arizona
- California
- Colorado
- Connecticut
- Delaware
- Hawaii
- Idaho
- Indiana
- Iowa
- Minnesota
- Mississippi
- Missouri
- Montana
- Nebraska
- New Hampshire
- New Mexico
- New York
- North Dakota
- Oklahoma
- Oregon
- Rhode Island
- South Carolina
- South Dakota
- Tennessee
- Texas
- Vermont
- West Virginia
- Wisconsin
- Wyoming

## States which require slower traffic to move right only if they are blocking traffic:

- Florida
- Georgia
- Nevada
- Utah
- Virginia

## States which require drivers moving slower than the speed limit to move right:

- Alaska
- Maryland
- North Carolina
- Ohio
- Puerto Rico

## States with other rules

- Michigan allows only passing on the left lane unless there is heavy traffic or more than three lanes on the freeway
- Pennsylvania and Washington allow use of the left lane to pass, allow traffic to merge, or "when traveling at a speed greater than the traffic flow."

Comment: First off in the state of New Jersey passing on the right is allowed on a multi-lane roads.  The link you provided states: `Passing on right prohibited unless vehicles are in "substantially continuous lines."`